# How to take value from <ajaxtoolkit:combobox runat="server" ID="ctlAramaKayitlari" ></ajaxtoolkit:combobox>

Tags: webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have ajaxtoolkit input field. I could not take the value from it in form side. Need help. Thank you.

```
 <ajaxtoolkit:combobox AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" runat="server" ID="ctlAramaKayitlari" ></ajaxtoolkit:combobox>
```

Answer (score 0):

ctlAramaKayitlari.SelectedValue; solved